# Snort Rules Configuration Issue

Tags: snort

I am new to snort so hope you can help me out. I am trying to create my own rules in snort via the local.rules file. I have snort installed on Windows 7 via Virtual box. My configuration seems to be working fine as I can test it with the string -T and it works fine. Also when I run the first three simple rules in the attached screenshot entitled snort rules they work fine, my problem is when I try to right a specific rule which in this case is to log when bit torrent is download the rule is triggered but I am getting all these http_inspect errors. Not sure what they are and if I am missing something in the snort.conf file. I have not touched the preprocessor settings in snort.conf. The errors I get are also attached in the screenshot Snort Output. The rule syntax I am running is snort -i 1 -c c:\snort\etc\snort.conf -A console. The rule is getting logged in the log folder and also I attach the wireshark output. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Garreth

[image: Snort Output]
[image: Snort Rules]

Answer (score 2):

The messages from http_inspect are not errors with your config or errors at all, they are messages from preprocessor rules that are triggering from the traffic. Specifically rule 120:3:1 (GID = 120, SID = 3, REV = 1). The GID 120 rules are specific to the http server inspection from the http preprocessor. This rule generates an event when the http_inspect preprocessor detects anomalous network traffic. The message for this rule is "NO CONTENT-LENGTH or TRANSFER-ENCODING". What this rule is looking at is the server response headers. It's likely alerting because there was no "Content-Length" header or there was no "Transfer-Encoding" header in the response header.

Here is an example of http server response headers:

accept-ranges:bytes
content-length:67023552
content-type:application/x-apple-diskimage
date:Thu, 10 Mar 2016 05:32:31 GMT
server:downloads
status:200

There should always be a content-length header in the server response because it tells the client how much data there is for this request. When the actual length of the data is different than what is presented in the content-length header the client should discard it and throw an error. If there is no content-length header the client has no idea how much data is about to be sent and there is no way to validate that it got all of the data for this request. If this header is missing from the server response snort will generate the rule you are seeing because this is anomalous traffic. It could also be missing the [transfer-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#transfer-encoding-response-header) header. In the example above you'll notice there is not transfer-encoding, so snort would generate this rule if the server response headers looked like the above. The transfer-encoding header is not in a lot of http responses, and this is normal. I believe that these rules are generated when you have the "extended_response_inspection" and the text rules are set to alert (do you have a preprocessor.rules file snort is picking up, or is this rule in any of your rule files?). This option is explain in the snort manual for the [http server configuration options](http://manual.snort.org/node17.html#SECTION00327800000000000000). If you don't care about these alerts you can remove the gid rules from your rules files. If you do not have these rules in your rules files then you can add the "no_alerts" option to the http server config. From the snort manual for this option:

"This option turns off all alerts that are generated by the HTTP Inspect preprocessor module. This has no effect on HTTP rules in the rule set. No argument is specified."

You can also remove the extended_response_inspection options from the http config if the rule is being generated by that option.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your tcp config is missing the client/server/both
keyword between ports and 80.  Consequently, 80 is being lost and
reassembly is set to both for 8080 only.  Change to this in config file:

```
                  preprocessor stream5_tcp: policy first, ports 80 8080
```

This means that every HTTP port needs to be listed in the stream5_tcp preprocessor and that this is not 
enforced.

For more info on setting up snort, please go through the following links:
https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/05/snort-how-does-it-work/
https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/05/snort-an-open-source-ids-in-freebsd-10-or-above/
https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/10/snort-performance-is-your-snort-working-fast-enough/